# How does ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol work?

Tags: c#

I would like to know how the property `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` works when I set three different `SecurityProtocolType` on her flags. Ie.,

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Will the communication try first to communicate with `TLS`, and if it fails try  `TLS1.2` and after `SSL3`?

If not, what do these flags mean and how does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whichever communication object you're using (HttpClient, HttpWebRequest, etc) will try to negotiate to the highest level possible first. Failing that it will keep going "down" the chain.

If you're using .Net 4.6 then the default security protocols will look like this because SSL3 is broken:

```
SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

If you really need to use SSL3 for some reason and are using .Net 4.6, see this MS KB article on how to force it to be insecure: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3069494

You might also be asking how this protocol level is actually determined? This is step 1 of the SSL handshake process where each end of the connection says "I support this version". Here is an interesting read on the full handshake process: http://www.truedigitalsecurity.com/blog/2015/05/20/ssltls-protocol-version-negotiation/

Comment: Thank you by the answer. It was exactly what I was searching.

Comment: I have one more doubt, if the client-side accepts only TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 but the server accepts only TLS 1.2, the communication will be realized with success? Have tls 1.2 in server compatibility with tls 1.1 in client ?

Comment: If the server only supports 1.2 and nothing else, you had better have 1.2 in your ServicePointManager or it won't work. This sort of thing happened when SSLv3 was deprecated and some servers only supported SSLv3 still, yet .Net 4.6 doesn't by default so communication broke down. Having 1.0/1.1/1.2 is a safe bet for now. Revisit this once 1.0 gets broken.

Comment: Try this update link for the truedigitalsecurity blog post: https://truedigitalsecurity.com/blog/ssl-tls-protocol-version-negotiation

Comment: edit queue full, broken link, new link: https://truedigitalsecurity.com/blog/ssl-tls-protocol-version-negotiation