# Azure Service Bus TLS Version migration

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, tls1.2

My company recently decided that they will be manually enforcing TLS v1.2 on our Azure Service Bus instance (currently sitting on TLS v1.0)

As such I was tasked to ensure that our systems are compatible with TLS v1.2 when we eventually do switch over, however I'm stuck on trying to understand this line of code which asserts the TLS version in our services:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Can someone please explain what the `|` pipeing means in this code? And if we were to switch over to TLS v1.2, would this code be sufficient or do I need to modify this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-or-operator-

Comment: @GauravMantri it does somewhat but my main question is if this line of code will work if the endpoint only accepts TLS v1.2?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925001/how-does-servicepointmanager-securityprotocol-work